# Rails passing local variable from view to js, controller and then back to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am selecting a customer from drop down menu and based on selection it should display departments in next drop down.

But it is giving undefined local variable or method f

```
NameError at /cus_departments
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x000001078cbf88>:0x0000010782a138>
```

Here is my view file

new.html.haml

```
.page-content
  .page-header
    %h1 New agreement
  .row
    .col-xs-12
      = render :partial => 'form'
.actions
  = link_to 'Back', agreements_path
```

_form.html.haml

```
= form_for @agreement, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal', :role => 'form'} do |f|
  .form-group
    %label.col-sm-3.control-label.no-padding-right.form-field-2
      = f.label :agreement_customer, 'Agreement customer'
  .col-sm-9
    #form-field-2.col-xs-10.col-sm-5.input.movies
      = f.select :agreement_customer, options_from_collection_for_select(Customer.all, :id, :customer_name), prompt: true
  .space-4
  .form-group
    %label.col-sm-3.control-label.no-padding-right.form-field-2
      = f.label :agreement_customer_dept, 'Customer department'
    .col-sm-9
      #form-field-2.col-xs-10.col-sm-5.input.characters
        %select{:class => 'form-control'}
          %option
  .space-4
```

agreement.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('.input.movies select').change ->
    url = "/cus_departments?customer_id=" + $(this).val() # get the selected value from the drop-down
    $('.input.characters select').load(url) # load the response from the url into the specified element(s)
```

agreements_controller.rb

```
def cus_departments

@customer = Customer.find_by_id(params[:customer_id])
@departments = @customer.departments

    render :partial => 'departments'
end
```

_departments.html.haml

```
= collection_select(:department, :customer_id, @departments, :id, :department, :prompt => "Select a department")
```

Can somebody help me please on this?

Answer (score 0):

What you provided is little bit confusing, but from my understand I think the problem is with loading the retrieved values to select box. User remote javascript or rjs those are powerful and perfect for this type of requirement. If you wish I will send some code sample. :)

Comment: can you please help me how to make this working with some easy solution if you have any?

Comment: Are you still struggling ?

Comment: No I got the solution but with different way. Thanks.